# Tensorflow - training weights via GD by hand

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I want to train a toy neural network to solve the xor problem. I want to be able to pass in two bits as inputs and have 1 bit as an output. I will have 4 training examples: `[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]`

I understand how the forward feed works but I do not exactly know how I would optimize the weights?

I do not want to use a built in function such as

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(mse)
```

Instead I want to calculate the deltas and gradients by for each individual node (with respect to how many deltas and gradiants are needed for the node type)

I can take in the Y_hat and subtract from the true Y to get my error. I can then calculate my delta for this output and calculate the deltas for the hidden nodes. Using the deltas I can calculate my gradiants. Using these gradiants I can calculate how much I need to change each weight by.

My issue is with updating the weights, since I am giving the session.run 4 inputs (the training examples) When I update the weights I get a dimention error because there are 4 training examples and the weights are for each example not 4 at a time.

I am not sure how I would update the weights for each sample individually.

Here is some code that I have written:

```
'''
Simple neural network to solve the xor problem
2 inputs representing bits of the xor gate
1 output representing the output bit of the xor gate
'''

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# build computational graph
n_input = 2
n_hidden = 2
n_classes = 1

#weights describing which layer it is affecting
#ie h1 affects layer 1
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])),# inputs x hidden
    'ol': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
#biases describing which layer it is affecting
#ie b1 affects layer 1
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'ol': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
        }

def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))

def forward(x, weights, biases):
    # 1st hidden layer
    layer1 = tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']) + biases['b1'] #w*x + b
    layer1 = sigmoid(layer1, False)#sigmoid activation

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer1, weights['ol']), biases['ol']) #w*x + b
    output = sigmoid(output, False)#sigmoid activation
    return output

def optimizer(out):
    return tf.trainable_variables()

x = tf.placeholder('float', None, name='X_value_placeholder')

pred = forward(x, weights, biases)

opt = optimizer(pred)

x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0,0.0]])
# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1):
        print 'epoch {}'.format(i)
        print (sess.run(opt, feed_dict={x: x_vals}))
```

From my understanding I need to do the following for optimizing the weights:

**Deltas:**

*Hidden nodes (using layer 1 as an example):*

- `sigmoid(l1_sums, True) * ol_deltas * weights['h1']`

*output node:*

- `-E * sigmoid(self.sums, True)`

**Gradiants:**

- `l1_outputs * ol_deltas`

**Update Weights**

- `l1_gradiants*learning_rate + momentum * l1_weight_deltas`

**TLDR:**

To sum it up, how can optimize the weights (apply these functions) to the graph for a batch input as opposed to running the graph for every sample?

Answer (score 0):

In the usual approach, you use dimension 0 as the batch dimension. You are doing this for `x` in `x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0,0.0]])` (assuming `(1,0)` and `(0,0)` are your two training examples for `x`). You write your graph operations in such a way that they work for any actual value during the forward pass (this is useful in practice if you want to play with setting the mini-batch size). In particular, this means that your output from the forward pass will be a vector of predictions, instead of being one value. Finally, when computing the gradient, you would first compute the gradient for each example in your mini-batch, then, average them to get the gradient for the whole mini-batch. Here is a coursera lecture about this - https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/9zJUs/mini-batch-gradient-descent.